# Daemon not working correctly in --background (ubuntu, start-stop-daemon)

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, webrtc

I'm trying to start 'peerconnection_server' from webrtc as a daemon with this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Start/stop server2

NAME=peerserver2
PIDFILE=/var/www/peerserver2.pid


CMD=/var/www/temp/webrtc/trunk/out/Debug/peerconnection_server


do_start() {
    start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $CMD --make-pidfile
}

do_stop() {
    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE
}

case "$1" in
start)
    echo -n "Starting $NAME \n"
    do_start
        ;;
stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $NAME \n"
    do_stop
    ;;
restart)
    echo -n "Restarting $NAME \n"
    do_stop
    do_start
    ;;
*)
    echo -n "Usage: /etc/init.d/server2 {start|stop|restart} \n"
    exit 2
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

It's starts after `server2 start` command and I see this process in `ps -aux | grep server`, but `peerconnection_server` is not working well. When I try to connect to my `peerconnection_server` it accepts my `sign_in` request but it does not do what it should do.

But if I execute the same command from locale:
 `/var/www/temp/webrtc/trunk/out/Debug/peerconnection_server`

...it works perfectly.

Can anyone help my with this case? Maybe I need to set options? 
Also in my `peerconnection_server` I use the `system()` command from c++. 
Also the program uses port 8888.

Thank You.

updated:

I solved this problem by 'screen'-command. Just writed bash-script with infinite loop. In whis loop I start new screen if proccesses do not contain it already. It work but I think it realy not elegant decision.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that is does not like being in the background (which the manual states should be a last resort). Does it work equally wrong when you start it like `/var/www/temp/webrtc/trunk/out/Debug/peerconnection_server &`? If so, check the code why it does not want to do that.

Comment: When I executing it with `var/www/temp/webrtc/trunk/out/Debug/peerconnection_server &` it work correctly.

Comment: My best guess is, when you start it manually its `stdin`,`stdout` and `stderr` are bound to your `tty`. When starting it via init script it usually doesn't have any associated `tty`. Running it with `screen` forces an allocation of `tty`. Modify your code to stop using `tty` based `I/O` and you should be able able to run it without `screen`.

Comment: thank you. i'd like to avoid to use the screen in this case. but thanks anyway